# How to Access String In Another Fragment in Android

Tags: android, string, bundle

I am trying to access a String from an EditText on my login page to use in my other fragments. I found some information on using Bundle to achieve this, but I am having some difficulty implementing this function. I have a temporary TextView I am assigning the String to so I can tell when it is working, so ignore this object(tvGetTest).

Login Class:

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
    etAccountNumber = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.etAccountNumber);
    rbGroup = (RadioGroup) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rbGroup);
    rbUsa = (RadioButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rbUsa);
    rbCanada = (RadioButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rbCanada);
    btnLogin = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

    Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(accountNumber, accountNumber);
    bundle.putString(countryCode, countryCode);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            doLogin();
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}

public void doLogin() {
    accountNumber = etAccountNumber.getText().toString();

    if (rbUsa.isChecked()) {
        countryCode = "USA";
    }
    else if (rbCanada.isChecked()) {
        countryCode = "CAN";
    }

}
```

onCreate of Other Fragment Class:

```
tvGetTest = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvGetTest);

    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
        String aNo = bundle.getString("accountNumber");
        tvGetTest.setText(aNo);

    }
```

Edit:

```
public void doBundle() {
    Fragment fragment = new AvailabilityFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(accountNumber, accountNumber);
    bundle.putString(countryCode, countryCode);
    fragment.getFragmentManager().putFragment(bundle, accountNumber, fragment);
    fragment.getFragmentManager().putFragment(bundle, countryCode, fragment);
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `Fragment`? you should be using a class that extends Fragment.. and second, from where are you adding the other fragment? I think you should do that in your activity;

Comment: Can you elaborate? I have a fragment called AvailabilityFragment which extends Fragment. I referred to this class in my post as "Other Fragment Class".

Comment: You should have in your activity a method that adds the other fragment, that method takes the arguments `accountNumber` and `countryCode`, puts them in a bundle, puts that bundle in your new fragment and adds fragment via fragmentmanager. Then, you call that method in your `doLogin`.

Comment: I added an edit, is this correct?

Comment: No, it isn't. I'll try to clear things up in an answer.

Comment: You have a Fragment in a Fragment. That doesn't seem right.

Comment: Ok thanks, my end game here is I want to be able to access the accountNumber and countryCode strings, which are created through user input on the login fragment, in my other fragments as these items are parameters for those fragments.

Comment: @GarrettMarschke see my answer for passing arguments to the other fragment. As to getting arguments in the other fragment, your code should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's preferable to manage all your fragments from their host activity, avoid nesting fragments.
In your use case, you should define a method in your `HostActivity` called `launchOtherFragment`:

```
public void launchOtherFragment(String accountNumber, String countryCode)
{
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("accountNumber", accountNumber);
    bundel.putString("countryCode", countryCode);
    OtherFragment fragment = new OtherFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();
}
```

Now you can access this method in your first fragment, so in `doLogin`:

```
private void doLogin() {
    accountNumber = etAccountNumber.getText().toString();

    if (rbUsa.isChecked()) {
        countryCode = "USA";
    }
    else if (rbCanada.isChecked()) {
        countryCode = "CAN";
    }

    ((HostActivity)getActivity()).launchOtherFragment(accountNumber, countryCode);
}
```

Comment: I am using a TabLayout, so I am not sure if I have a HostActivity but I do have a MainActivity. I tried to implement here, but OtherFragment cannot be resolved.